# Enable Async CTP in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, async-ctp

I've been using VS2010 to develop all my applications on my Windows 8 box for a while, no major issues everything is fine.

However, today I opened a windows phone 7 project that has used the Async CTP libraries and of course noticed that 'async' keyword is invalid.

No worries, off to install the CTP.

I installed the CTP, then restarted VS and opened the project. No dice. The reference to AsyncCtpLibrary is working (in fact I use nu get for it), but nothing I seem to do fixes this issue. From what I know it means that the Async CTP didn't successfully modify the C# compiler (or something).

Anybody have this working in Windows 8? I can't find anything anywhere so thought I'd ask the SO gurus :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use VS 2012? I think that's the best option. Among other things because it contains bug fixes and improvements that are not in the CTP.

Comment: I hadn't heard that vs2012 is able to edit windows phone projects just yet... this is my dev box and so all my code bases are vs2010-based and I don't want to risk functionality leaking in that clients can't use.

Comment: confirmed. installed vs2012, can't open WP projects

Answer (score 4):

You can use Windows 8 + Visual Studio 2010 + Windows Phone 7 SDK + [AsyncCTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) together, although there is one small problem during the installation.

First you need to install Visual Studio 2010, then install SP1 for Visual Studio 2010, then Windows Phone SDK and then immediately AsyncCTP v3 for Visual Studio 2010 and after this run the Windows Update.

If you install updates to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 before installing AsyncCTP, the installation of AsyncCTP fails because of collision with some Visual Studio hotfixes.

I've found the [solution here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/async-ctp-fix-installation-problem.aspx) together with some trial&error installing and uninstalling :)

**Update:** for Visual Studio 2012 the only solution for async/await in other project types is the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) library, available on NuGet.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/11/01/async-ctp-v3-installation.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx